# Spring-boot AOP not working with maven

Tags: java, maven, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to implement AOP in spring-boot with the help of custom annotation and Around advice. I am adding the annotation before a GET api but i am not able to catch the function in my Aspect.

pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>1.8.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

HiveService.java

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface HiveService{
//public String name() default "";
}
```

Followup.java

```
@HiveService
@RequestMapping(value="rest/services/{pr 
oduct}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public String getFollowupCategoryList(@PathVariable String product) {
    LOGGER.info("[getFollowupCategoryList]: started again ");
}
```

HiveConsumer.java

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class HiveConsumer {


@Around("@annotation(com.abc.xyz.HiveService)")
public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.abc.xyz.FollowupController.class);
    LOGGER.info("Before");

    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

    long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    LOGGER.info(joinPoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + executionTime + "ms");
    return proceed;
}
}
```

Configuration file for Spring AOP

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class ActivitiRestApplication extends 
SpringBootServletInitializer  {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
}
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder app) {
    return app.sources(applicationClass);
}

private static Class<ActivitiRestApplication> applicationClass = ActivitiRestApplication.class;
```

Comment: Three questions: Why would you mix AspectJ runtime 1.6.11 with weaver 1.8.12? Does any other aspect run, maybe a simple `execution(* *(..))`? Furthermore, how did you configure Spring AOP in your application? You did not share any information about that.

Comment: Added the configuration file

Answer (score 0):

The application runs nicely if you

- add dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.3.RELEASE` to your POM,
- remove the redundant `org.aspectj:aspectjrt` because it is a subset of `org.aspectj:aspectjweaver` (and you had specified a non-matching version umber anyway),
- add `@RestController` to your class containing the annotated method,
- make method `getFollowupCategoryList(..)` actually return a string (in your sample code it does not return anything, thus does not even compile).

Here is the fixed version of your code as a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. including package and class names. I changed the logging code to use `System.out` so as to minimise dependencies for the sake of this demo.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.scrum-master.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-51512380</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <version>1.8.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Update:** Actually, you can even reduce your POM to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.scrum-master.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-51512380</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface HiveService {
  //public String name() default "";
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SomeClass {
  @HiveService
  @RequestMapping(value = "rest/services/{product}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
  public String getFollowupCategoryList(@PathVariable String product) {
    System.out.println("[getFollowupCategoryList]: started again");
    return "foo";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class ActivitiRestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  private static Class<ActivitiRestApplication> applicationClass = ActivitiRestApplication.class;

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder app) {
    return app.sources(applicationClass);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class HiveConsumer {
  @Around("@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.HiveService)")
  public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Before");
    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
    long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + executionTime + "ms");
    return proceed;
  }
}
```

Now if you run the application and open URL http://localhost:8080/rest/services/something in a web browser, it will display `foo` in the browser and this on the console:

```
Before
[getFollowupCategoryList]: started again
String de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.getFollowupCategoryList(String) executed in 2ms
```